# Enumerative or Gromov-Witten invariants from derived category of coherent sheaves

Tags: derived-categories, gromov-witten-theory, mirror-symmetry, enumerative-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective toric Fano surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose I have a nice presentation of $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ given by a full, strong exceptional collection $\mathcal{E} = \{E_i\}_{i\in I}$ of line bundles. There is an exact equivalence of $\mathbb{C}$-linear triangulated categories $$D^b_{Coh}(X) \stackrel{RHom(G,-)}{\rightarrow} (mod-A) $$ where $A = End_{D^b(X)}(G,G)$ and $G = \bigoplus_{i \in I} E_i $ as above. 1) I'm not sure whether this exact equivalence also carries through to the dg enhancement of $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ (I believe the answer is yes, I just don't know of a good reference for this). 2) My question is the following: Is it possible to extract enumerative or Gromov-Witten invariants from $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ alone? Are there cases when this is possible, by changing the assumptions on $X$? I've heard that we might need a stability condition on $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ or a principally-polarized abelian variety in this setting. Any references on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In a silly way, you can extract everything: by Orlov theorem, smooth variety with nontrivial canonical bundle is uniquely determined by its bounded derived category. Reasonable question would be whether those invariants can be seen purely categorically; but it's very unlikely, at least without monoidal structure, because in this case you can hardly differentiate objects corresponding to sheaves with different dimensions of support.

Comment: What do you mean by monoidal structure here?

Comment: By monoidal structure I mean monoidal structure. Bifunctor of derived tensor product. By the way, data of $D_b(Coh)$ as a triangulated category + tensor product reconstructs any qcqs scheme whatsoever, regardless of smoothness or anything.

Comment: Let's pause here and unpack what you are saying. By bifunctor you mean a bifunctor from D^b_{Coh}(X) -> D^b_{Coh}(X), and you mean that to start we don't have a derived tensor product on D^b_{Coh}(X) in general? Do you mean we don't have a tensor product as a k-linear triangulated category, or don't have a tensor product as dg enhanced? I don't see why D^b_{Coh}(X) doesn't have tensor products as a k-linear category? Or is it just that tensor product in general doesn't give a bifunctor?

Comment: What I mean is that tensor product is additional structure on a triangulated category. To wit: abelian variety and its dual always have equivalent $D_b(Coh)$'s, as well as any pair of CY threefolds; but any monoidal (wrt usual derived tensor product) equivalence $D_b(Coh X) \cong D_b(Coh Y)$ implies that $X \cong Y$. So you need to clarify what extra structure on derived category you're going to use, if any. Do you look at it as a plain triangulated category? As an $(\infty, 1)$ category? Do you fix some dg-enhancement? Do you fix some classical generator?

Comment: To start, I view $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ as a "plain" (in your words) k-linear triangulated category, à la the construction of a derived category of an abelian category in Weibel, Huybrechts, or Hartshorne. In this setting, Bondal's exact equivalence of $k$-linear categories gives a presentation of $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ as right modules over the endomorphism algebra above. There, I believe we would call a "classical generator" $G$ as above. I'm not sure whether this equivalence also carries through for dg categories, or A_infty categories [I believe that it does, but I don't know a good reference].

Comment: I would like to say that in the presence of $\mathcal{E}$ as a strong, full exceptional collection above that we also have a presentation of $D^b_{Coh}(X)$ as a dg-enhanced or $\infty$-category. But again, I can't prove this and don't know a good reference. 

Ultimately my question was about the amount of structure or data that must be imposed in order to extract enumerative or Gromov-Witten invariants. Yes, part of the reason I started with a smooth projective toric Fano variety is because $D^b(X)$ determines $X$ here, but also because (in practice) I have a way of writing these things down